# Magento 2.3.3 installation with composer fails: Could not delete

Tags: magento2, composer, exception, vagrant, runtime

I'm trying to install Magento 2.3.3 on Debian 9 over a [virtual machine](https://github.com/zepgram/magento2-fast-vm).

I'm stuck during the magento installation process because of the magento-composer-installer plugin. I also did a manual installation using the following command from the magento [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/before/before-setup-env-2_clone.html#branch), but I always get the same error:

```
composer --no-ansi --no-interaction install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    Finished: success: 0, skipped: 0, failure: 334, total: 334
Package operations: 460 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.13): Loading from cache
Plugin installation failed, rolling back
  - Removing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.13)


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /home/vagrant/magento/magento2/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon:
```

I'm using Windows 10 as host machine.

Composer 1.9.2 
PHP 7.2 
Vagrant 2.2.6 
Virtual Box 6.0.16

Do you have any idea how to resolve that error? I saw a similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293924/magento-2-3-3-instal-with-composer-fails-without-show-any-motivation), but no really relevant answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution [here](https://github.com/zepgram/magento2-fast-vm/issues/48) while disscussing with the virtual machine's developer.